# Can a private on-premises New Relic instance be set up?

Tags: cloud, private, newrelic-platform

I've use case where we want to setup Relic server on premises. Don't want share logs with hosted Relic server i.e `collector.newrelic.com`.

Is it possible to setup whole Relic Server in virtual private network i.e on Virtual Machine? And relic agent will use this private relic server i.e installed and configured on premises or on VM.

Comment: Could you contact New Relic about this and ask them?

Answer (score 0):

According to a [discussion on New Relic's forums](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/new-relic-all-in-one-on-premise-setup/32131) an on-premise option for New Relic isn't and will likely never be available. Lew Cirne, the CEO and founder of New Relic, mentioned in his [FutureStack15 keynote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tk0gGDsmUtQ&feature=youtu.be&t=1656) that on-premise deployments wouldn't be viable because New Relic's data querying and analysis capabilities can only be cost-effective in a multi-tenant environment.